# How do u recover your iPad clash of clans account without the old device

Tags: clash-of-clans, ios

How do you recover iPad account without old device

Comment: Was the old device connected to any services? Was it on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

If you logged into Game Center, you don't need your old device, as upon logging in, it will automatically ask you if you want to load old village. To that, you can click yes, Clash will reload, and you have your old village.

I am not sure if the old to new device feature actually works without signing in. But if yes, you might be able to contact Supercell support, and show them your account (if you know your village tag or you have a unique name)